# I cannot scrape all the products on an an Aliexpress page

Tags: html, r, web-scraping, rvest

I'm trying to scrape all the products on the an Aliexpress page with the code as follow but it only returns 10 first products.

I have attempted with the following codes when I expected it to return all the products as the CSS Selector selects all the product name. [Here is the picture.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NqJ6p.jpg)

```
AlPage <- "https://www.aliexpress.com/w/wholesale-running-shoes.html?SearchText=running+shoes&catId=0&g=n&initiative_id=SB_20230318171033&sortType=total_tranpro_desc&spm=a2g0o.home.1000002.0&trafficChannel=main"

url<-read_html(AlPage)

print(url)

alproduct_name<-html_nodes(url,".manhattan--title--24F0J-G, .cards--title--2rMisuY") %>% html_text2()
alproduct_name
```

I also have checked the class name for all the products, as I thought they might have different classes name but they are all the same.

Comment: I’m guessing this is against the terms of service (TOS). You may be asking us to assist you in an illegal activity.

Comment: Oh no I just scrape the data, nothing to do with the TOS or go against it.

Comment: Copied from thie  website's "Terms of Use" ::: `You agree that (a) you will not copy, reproduce, download, re-publish, sell, distribute or resell any Services or any information, text, images, graphics, video clips, sound, directories, files, databases or listings, etc available on or through the Sites (the “Site Content”)`

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that the initial webpage only displays the first ten results and then the remaining results are loaded dynamically as the user scrolls down so you won't be able to easily do this with `rvest`. Here's how to do it with `RSelenium`:

I also changed the html node to h1. The node you found didn't work for me, but h1 still pulls the shoe names from this page.

```
# define url ---------------------------------------------------------
url <- "https://www.aliexpress.com/w/wholesale-running-shoes.html?SearchText=running+shoes&catId=0&g=n&initiative_id=SB_20230318171033&sortType=total_tranpro_desc&spm=a2g0o.home.1000002.0&trafficChannel=main"


# start RSelenium ------------------------------------------------------------

rD <- rsDriver(browser="firefox", port=4548L, chromever = NULL)
remDr <- rD[["client"]]

# Navigate to webpage -----------------------------------------------------
remDr$navigate(url)


# scroll to bottom of the page to load all the results
webElem <- remDr$findElement("css", "body")
webElem$sendKeysToElement(list(key = "end"))

# pull page html
html <- remDr$getPageSource()[[1]]

# Use Rvest to read the webpage
AlPage <-html %>% read_html()


# scan the webpage for the h1 node and pull the text associated with that node

alproduct_name <- AlPage %>% 
                  html_nodes("h1") %>% 
                  html_text2()

alproduct_name
```

Should be 46 results right?
[image: 46 results]